# Graph Theory - Show that every graph with at most three cycles is planar

Tags: graph-theory

While working through some problems concerning planarity, I encountered one asking me to prove that every graph with at most three cycles is planar. Being rather elementary in my knowledge of Graph Theory, I have tried approaching this through use of Kuratowski's Theorem:

A finite graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a sub-graph that is homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

However, from what I have observed $K_{3,3}$ has 10 cycles. In this way, recognizing that neither isolating a sub-graph nor subdividing said sub-graph can create new cycles, it would appear that a graph would need at least 10 cycles to be non-planar. I have been unable to identify any graph with fewer than ten cycles which proves non-planar. Any help as to what I am missing here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Without thinking too hard about the problem itself, one possibility is that the problem isn't asking you to prove an optimal statement. If it is true that any graph with fewer than 10 cycles is planar (I don't know yet if it is!), it is certainly also true that any graph with at most 3 cycles is planar.

Comment: Are you sure $K_{3,3}$ has only $10$ cycles? I count $9$ cycles of length $4$ and a bunch ($6$?) of cycles of length $6$.

Comment: I don't know what you're worried about. The problem is asking you to prove that every nonplanar graph has more than $3$ cycles, right? If you're allowed to use Kuratowski's theorem, then all you have to do is prove that $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ (and of course their subdivisions) have more than $3$ cycles. Looks like you've already done this for $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ should be just as easy if not easier.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I was thinking along a similar line. However, after looking more carefully at the book I believe the an optimal solution is required

Comment: @bof After recounting, I am fairly certain there are 15. I also found there to be 9 cycles of length 4, but only 5 cycles of length 6.

Comment: @bof As the question was phrased in my textbook, it seemed like having 3 cycles was a significant cut-off for guaranteed planarity. I figured I was likely missing something. Would it hold that all graphs with fewer cycles than $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ are planar?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work :

Let G be a graph with at most three cycles.

Without loss of generality we consider G to be a simple 2-connected graph.

(Why simple?  - because if G is non-planar, removal of loops and multiple edges of G must result in a subgraph of G which is also non-planar.

Why 2-connected? - A graph is planar if and only if each of it's blocks is planar. Hence, while testing the planarity of a graph G, one may assume G to be a block and hence 2-connected.)

Now, let G has only one cycle say C1 of length k, then all the vertices of G must be in C1 (otherwise since G cannot have any more cycles, G\C1 contains a tree connected to C1 by a cut-vertex of G - a contradiction to - G is 2-connected). Hence G itself is a cycle and hence is planar.

Let G has another cycle C2, then for a vertex u in C1 which is not in C2 and another vertex v in C2 which is not in C1, u & v must lie on a common cycle, say C3. (Since G is 2-connected). Now, G cannot have any more cycles and G is 2-connected implies C1 is adjacent to C2 (have a common set of adjacent edges) so that the cycle C3 can be formed.

Again, all the vertices of G must be in C1 or C2 (otherwise since G cannot have any more cycles, G \ C1UC2 contains a tree connected to C1 or C2 by a cut-vertex of G - a contradiction to - G is 2-connected). Therefore, G is a cycle adjoined to another cycle and hence is a planar graph having three faces.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).